# ¿Cómo reducir el tamaño de la página?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

Quiero reducir el tamaño de página. Si lo hago directamente con el teclado es suficiente con pulsar la combinación de teclas Ctrl+-. Pero con selenium no consigo hacerlo, no sé si es que estoy seleccionado el elemento equivocado o es que se hace de otra forma...

he probado a hacerlo así

```
 driver.find_element_by_tag_name('html').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + '-')
```

y así

```
 driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + '-')
```

y así

```
 driver.find_element_by_tag_name('html').send_keys(Keys.COMMAND + '-')
```

y así

```
 driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.COMMAND + '-')
```

Ninguna de estas formas ha funcionado pero tampoco da errores...

También he pensado que se podría ejecutar un código JavaScript para hacerlo con esta función

```
 driver.execute_script("document.body.style.zoom='50%'")
```

Pero tampoco funciona. ¿Alguna ídea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se que driver estás usando, pero voy a dejar una opción para ***geckodriver***. Al menos en geckodriver / Firefox las combinaciones de teclas que producen efectos a nivel del navegador en sí y no de contenido web, como es este caso, no funcionan intencionadamente. Si que hay combinaciones que funcionan como es el caso de <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> / <kbd>V</kbd>.

Yo al menos lo que hago es habilitar el "Chrome context", bien vía:

- Método `selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver.set_context`:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
  from time import sleep


  driver = webdriver.Firefox()
  driver.get("http://www.python.org")

  driver.set_context("chrome")
  win = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("window")

  for i in range(1, 5):
      print(f"Zoom {i}")
      win.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "-")
      sleep(2)
  ```
- `selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver.context`: mi opción preferida, ya que junto a `with`  permite que contexto solo sea activado para las acciones requeridas y es restaurado tras la terminación del bloque automáticamente:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
  from time import sleep


  driver = webdriver.Firefox()
  driver.get("http://www.python.org")

  with driver.context(driver.CONTEXT_CHROME):
      win = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("window")
      for i in range(1, 5):  
          print(f"Zoom {i}")
          win.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "-")
          sleep(2)
  ```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> **El código está testado en:**
>
> - Python 3.7
> - Selenium 3.14.0
> - GeckoDriver 0.21.0
> - Firefox Quantum 61.0.1

Comment: Hola @FJSevilla. El código funciona perfecto. Muchas gracias!! Aunque no termino de entender el por qué de poner en el contexto Chrome cuando el driver que se está usando es el de FireFox (geckodriver).

Comment: Osea... si lo entiendo pero no lo comprendo... es decir... No veo muy lógico el deshabilitar las combinaciones de teclas con el driver de FireFox para luego poder habilitarlas si se pone el contexto de Chrome... En fín, no sé si me expliqué bien... Lo importante es que funciona... Muchas Gracias!!